# Unit Test Case for custom exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Below main class and test class works fine but I would like to write more test cases to test the getters. Can you help please?

**Main class**:

```java
public final class AuthException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AuthException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

**Test class**:

```java
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class AuthExceptionTest {

    @Test
    public void authExceptionWithMessageThrowableTest(){
        AuthException authException = new AuthException("Testing the Exception class with message", new NullPointerException());
        assertEquals("Testing the Exception class with message", authException.getMessage());
        assertEquals(NullPointerException.class, authException.getCause().getClass());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I would argue that it even makes no sense to have a single test for this tiny class let alone add more unit tests.

Comment: can you suggest some sample test class please

Comment: Again, I suggest you don't even test the class. What would you be testing?

Comment: Unit testing exceptions alone makes no sense neither provides value. Just write tests for the pieces which actually throw it.